# Consulta con 3 tablas

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Tengo 3 tablas que son: Control, Compradores y Titulos. En mi tabla de Control tengo Codigo, Fecha, Estado, CompradoresId y TitulosId. En mi tabla de Compradores tengo Id y Nombre, Al igual que en mi tabla de Titulos que tengo Id y Nombre. Mi consulta General es la siguiente:

```
 public List<Control> Listar()
    {
        using (DBEntities DbContext = new DBEntities())
        {
            var Ver1 = (from ctrl in DbContext.Control
                            select ctrl).ToList();
            return Ver1;

        }
    }
```

cuando mando a llamar mi consulta. me muestra el Id de Compradores de igual manera de Titulos me muestra el Id. a lo que yo solo quiero que me muestre los nombres de las dos tablas de Compradores y Titulos. Como podría realizar dicha consulta?

Comment: Usualmente esto se hace definiendo propiedades de navegación en tu clase `Control` que apuntan a tus otras 2 clases. ¿Lo has hecho?

Comment: Pero cómo lo estás haciendo? Listas en algún momento la tabla padre, y/o su hijo? Recorda que necesitas los Id, en caso de que listes el padre en un DataGridView, podes extraer el dato del ID de ahí, de ahí podes hacer una consulta a su hijo con una expresión lambda y/o con linq. Y de ahí sacas el siguiente id para la otra tabla. Sería bueno que mostres un diagrama de la bd.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Todo esta en diseñar bien el dominio, antes de escribir una línea de código hay que comprender como opera y piensa el negocio, para eso tenemos el UML que nos sirve para abstraer el mundo real, para reconocer las entidades del negocio y sus atributos, según la información que has brindado me he tomado la libertad de modelar lo que puede ser tu dominio.

[image: Diseño de solución]

Según el dominio debe ser una copia fiel en la implementación de tu código y una copia fiel en tu base de datos.

Tus clase quedarían de la siguiente manera según tu diseño de solución.

Titulo

```
public class Titulo
{
    public int TituloId { get; set; }
    public string Nombre { get; set; }

    //Siempre y cuando deseas tener una colección de controles
    public virtual ICollection<Control> Controles { get; set; }
}
```

Comprador

```
public class Comprador
{
    public int CompradorId { get; set; }
    public string Nombre { get; set; }

    //Siempre y cuando deseas tener una colección de controles
    public virtual ICollection<Control> Controles { get; set; }
}
```

Control

```
namespace Dominio
{
    public enum EnumEstado : int { Activo = 1, Inactivo = 2}

    public class Control
    {
        public int ControlId { get; set; }
        public int CompradorId { get; set; }
        public int TituloId { get; set; }
        public string Codigo { get; set; }
        public DateTime Fecha { get; set; }
        public EnumEstado Estado { get; set; }

        //Propiedades de navegación
        public virtual Comprador Comprador { get; set; }
        public virtual Titulo Titulo { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Con esas propiedades de navegación podrás tener acceso a las otras entidades desde Control y elaborar tus querys usando linq to entities.

He creado una clase extendida de Control ControlExtend para poder crear la query ya que no pueden haber propiedades del mismo nombre.

ControlExtend

```
public class ControlExtend
{
    public string NombreComprador { get; set; }
    public string NombreTitulo { get; set; }
}
```

Tu consulta quedaría de la siguiente manera, en la cual uso las propiedades de navegación para tener acceso a las otras entidades.

```
public List<ControlExtend> ListarControles()
    {
        using (MyContext context = new MyContext())
        {
            var result = (from item in context.Controles
                          select new ControlExtend()
                          {
                              NombreComprador = item.Comprador.Nombre,
                              NombreTitulo = item.Titulo.Nombre
                          }).ToList();
            return result;
        }
    }
```

Saludos!